# scripted pipeline to create jenkins job for multiple repositories and trigger specific repo

Tags: .net, github, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

How to configure Jenkins job for multiple repositories using scripted pipeline and I would like to build particular repository which is getting changes out of these repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

Create mulitibranch pipeline and configure the source repository(Github, GIT etc.,), this will scan the repository for changes and build the respective branch. Use Jenkinsfile  for scripting pipeline behavior for different branch/branch types. Please refer to below links for more information:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/

https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/wiki/Setup-Jenkins-Multibranch-Pipeline-and-Organization

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the generic webhook trigger plugin. So you can set the webhook in all repos which shall be build by this specific pipeline.
In the pipeline you can detect which repo and branch triggered the current run. Then you check this specific repo and branch and build it.

Bitbucket for example sends in the post body all the information you need.